# Is there any option to convert JSON file to CSV in Python using classes/objects?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, type-conversion

I wanted to ask if there is any option to convert data given in JSON file to CSV using classes/objects? Is it more efficient than just simply using pd.read_json and converting it to DataFrame and then to CSV.

I already made a class and succesfully converted JSON file to list of objects, but what next?

PS. Keep in mind that I'm new to programming.

Comment: If you can convert your list of objects to a list of iterables, then the csv module of the standard library can help you to write that into a csv file

Comment: @SergeBallesta Okay. Hmm. Although is there any faster/more efficient way to convert JSON file from API and making a csv from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

let assume we have file ***data.json*** containing the following data

```
[
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith"},
{"firstname": "Ana", "lastname": "Smith"}
]
```

Here is the code for our script ***json_to_csv.py***

```
import json
import csv 

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


with open('example.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['firstname', 'lastname']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Which will produce CSV file with header line **firstname,lastname**

example.csv

```
firstname,lastname
John,Smith
Ana,Smith
```

Comment: Okay, it helped me a lot! Thank you!